# Why does "last seen" time not agree with time of last edit?

Tags: support

I noticed and edit made about 1 hour ago and left a comment about it, then I checked the user profile and it says last seen *15 hours ago*.

Does "last seen" not include edits to others' posts?

Screen shot of side-by-side windows available in edit history.

Comment: Do you think this could apply to mother meta? Why is this SpaceX?

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder I ask in both places. In [one case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308453/303080) my Q here was migrated there. I choose based on how likely I am to get "beat up" in main meta if my question is too dumb or the answer too obvious. Muscle memory I guess, maybe it's getting better now. Also this question sort-of singles out a user, and it might look like I was trying to do that intentionally if I posted there. Here people are more likely not to jump to conclusions. I'd have to rethink and reformat before asking there. While you may not agree, this is my answer to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, my question *does indeed* turn out to be a slightly dumb question [as I'd feared](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/998/why-does-last-seen-time-not-agree-with-time-of-last-edit#comment3883_998)! Luckily I didn't ask in the main meta.

I just noticed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/187148/51174) that an edit I'd made to another user's post a while ago appears to be 3 minutes old. This is because I have low rep in that site and the edit needed to be approved. (Got two points too, yay!)

> [image]